# using javascript in div reload

Tags: javascript, html, reload

I'm trying to create a website with live statistics. I have 2 problems that I can't figure out what I'm I doing wrong.

I have a div that reloads every 10 seconds using set interval getting data from the table in the database.

What I want is when I have an event lets say "Match started" to have a popup window/alert box so the user knows that the game has started.
My code for this one is:

```
if(($rs2['keyword']=='Match started')) {
    echo
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        alert('Match started');
    </script>";
}
```

At this point it only pops out when the whole page loads but not when the div reloads.

My second problem is similar. When there is an event like red card, I want the background to change color.

My code for this one is un the div is:

```
if(($rs2['keyword']=='RED CARD'))){
    echo '<script>bcolor()</script>';
```

and the code in javascript is:

```
<script>
function bcolor(){
document.body.setAttribute("style","background-color:red");
}
</script>
```

Any help will be great!!

Comment: Are you using ajax to get the data? if so, you could handle the response in javascript, this would cause the alert to actually pop up since all JS is usually loaded when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Here is little jquery script, which demonstrates cathing div change event:
http://jsfiddle.net/CCLq5/1/

When the demo button is clicked, it will change the div contents and the event will be caught with:

```
$('div#a').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
  alert("div changed");
});
```